# Using removed Babel 5 option: base.modules - Use the correspondi ng module transform plugin

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am getting the following error when running the react application using babel and webpack.

Error
Using removed Babel 5 option: base.modules - Use the correspondi
ng module transform plugin in the `plugins` option. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#modules

This if my .babelrc file

```
{
"presets": [
"es2015",
[{"modules": true}],
"react"
],
"plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread","transform-runtime"]
}
```

This is my webpack files

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS), //Tells React to build in prod mode. https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.htmlnew webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.bundle.js'),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['react']
        }
      }
    ],
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /(\.js|\.jsx)$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'), loaders: ['babel', 'eslint']},
      {test: /jquery/, loader: 'expose?$!expose?jQuery'},
      {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/i, loaders: ['file']},
      {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
      {test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/, loaders: ['style',
      `css?${JSON.stringify({
            //sourceMap: true,
            // CSS Modules https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules
            //modules: true,
            //localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:3]'
          })}`,
      'postcss',
      `sass?${JSON.stringify({
          data: '$assets-path: \'../assets/\';',
          includePaths: ['./node_modules']
          })}`
      ]}
    ]
  },

  postcss: function () {
    return [autoprefixer({browsers:["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "Firefox ESR", "Safari 8"]})];
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions:["", ".jsx", ".js"]
  }
```

Could someone let me know what is this error related to?

Comment: I had the same problem. solution was nested array for presets
 [issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9679)